# ServerFault's error page has StackOverflow branding

Tags: bug, status-completed

This is what I just got as an error page on SF:

[image: screenshot of a serverfault URL displaying an error which is branded with stackoverflow logo, etc.]

On the plus side, I've been on SF for more than a year and I'm almost sure that I've seen an error outside of scheduled maintenance. Nice! :-)

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63407/intermittent-offline-messages, though that was a couple of days ago now.

Comment: Maybe it *was* a stack overflow? ;-)

Comment: See ChrisF's comment; they're testing new caching software and it hasn't been setup to give different Offline Messages for the various SE sites yet (or it hadn't at the time anyway).

Answer (score 5):

We have our own now
[image]